# what does "even as" mean in this paragraph

Tags: grammar

> But the dividing line between this role and that of paramount leader
> is ill-defined. Tensions can ensue. Mao Zedong felt he had to draw his
> prime minister, Zhou Enlai, close “**even as** he raised the whip and
> sometimes lashed the man he could not live without”, wrote Gao
> Wenqian, a historian, in a biography of Zhou published in 2008.

Is as a conjunction or adverb?what the sentence means?

Comment: Have you looked up the meanings of both words? "Even" is an adverb here, and "as" is a conjunction.

Comment: I have looked up,but the definition a dictionary give  seems unrelavent in the paragraph

Comment: even as - phrase - 'at the same time as' [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/even-as)

Comment: do you think “even as” here is better translated as "at the same time as" instread of "although"

Comment: 'Even as' is a good expression to use, for the reason I give in my answer below. 'Although' does not convey the same meaning of simultaneous action.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Answer (score 1):

We use 'even as' to say that one thing happened at the same time as something else, when there is something notable, surprising, or significant about the events, when we consider them together. The significance could be surprising coincidence, perceived irony, sadness, apparent contradiction, etc.

Mao Zedong drew Zhou Enlai close even as he raised the whip... Mao drawing Zhou close seems puzzling, surprising or interesting because he also at the same time criticised him.

*My mother said drinking was a bad habit even as she raised the bottle of whisky to her lips.

Even as I called my sick dog's name, I saw that he had died.

Even as he ran panting into the railway station, he saw the train leaving.*

Comment: thank your explanation,I have ask several people,but they seem didn't give a plausible answer as well as yours